# Laravel + Vue + Axios: DOM not updating from within Axios call, even though 'this' DOES update

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am learning Laravel + Vue. I have got stuck on a really odd problem:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <li v-for='category in categories' v-bind:key='category.id'>
            {{ category.title }}
        </li>
        {{ test }} 
    </div>    
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ExampleComponent',
        data() {
            return {
                categories: [],
                test: "test"
            }
        },
       mounted() {
            this.categories.push({'title': 'test1', 'desc': 'test1 desc'}, {'title': 'test2', 'desc': 'test2 desc'});
            this.test = "fwibble";
            axios.get('/api/categories')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);                
                this.test = "wibble";
                this.categories = response.data;
                console.log(this);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I run it, the following happens:

The first `this.categories` and `this.title` behave as expected. The page displays the two dummy categories, and {{ test }} is set to "fwibble".

All the console.logs fire.

When I console.log `response`, it looks as expected (has a couple of categories from my backend)
When I console.log `this`, it looks as though it has updated (so test: wibble, and categories contains an array of the data from the backend)

However, the new data does not display. It's like I can't change the DOM from within the axios call.

When googling for a solution, the most common problem is "this" not being what's expected, but I'm referencing the correct thing with "this" (as checked in the console.logs)

Just in case it's something to do with the wider project, here is my repo: https://github.com/StarfallProjects/scheduler

I am running the frontend with `npm run watch`

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Maybe you can use this.$forceUpdate(); ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mohammad.kaab, but unfortunately it still doesn't update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app is mounted twice in `layout.blade.php` as it has two `app.js` script tags (at line 13 and line 79).

You should remove the second one because the first script tag deferred; it will be executed when the page has finished parsing.

Also, you might face some bugs because you have two elements with id `app`. The first at `layout.blade.php` and the other in `welcome.blade.php`. You can remove the second one as it is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh wow . . . ok I now feel thoroughly stupid :p Thank you so much for taking the time to look at the full project! Really really appreciate it!